# Access Deleted Data or Free Space in memory of Android devices?

Tags: android, flutter, storage, recovery

I am trying to create an Android application which attempts to retrieve deleted/lost data in Android devices. Is there anyway to do this? I prefer to use Flutter, but willing to use any other tech stack. I think, we might need to use low level languages. Can anyone help me out :)

The thing is, we need to access the segment of memory/storage which is not in the directory and not visible in the file explorer. And we plan to use some algorithms to make sense of the data/bits we get and show it to the user

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible. You can never do it with an Android application.
Accessing the free space with an android kernel is not possible.

You can try to use memory of the phone pretend to be a hard disk and use EaseUS Data Recovery on Windows